# How can make the icon alive in my AWT button()? On click the icon goes away

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

How can i keep the icon always alive, on click it does not get reloaded.

```
public static class SoftButton extends Button 
{
    private Image image;

    public SoftButton() 
    {            
        setLabel("test");
        setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {  
        super.paint(g);
        image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/tmp/world.gif");
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `AWT` components in the first place? Also, you may want to check out [An Image Button Class](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/CWP-Chapter13/CWP-Chapter13.3.html).

Comment: -1, You've already been given an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718944/how-to-make-awt-button-and-use-imageicon-icon/6719006#6719006. And yes the solution is far more complicated then the code you posted so don't expect us to write the code for you when you already have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local variable in which you store the Icon. Like you almost did:

```
public static class SoftButton extends Button 
{
    private Image image;

    public SoftButton() 
    {            
        setLabel("test");
        setBackground(Color.red);
        // Load the icon once in the constructor:
        image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/tmp/world.gif");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {  
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this will resolve OP's problem, although it's good advice.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: This way still does not work. First it shows icon. On click the icon goes away, and never comes back. Its same like my posted code still.