# Jbuttons transparent look needed

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, transparency, look-and-feel

I am using Java Netbeans GUI Builder for making GUI. I want to give the buttons a transparent (glossy) look.I am using

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

which also gives nice look to GUI but the buttons are still the same boring buttons.

So,how to give buttons a transparent look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
button.setOpaque(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false); //to make the content area transparent
button.setBorderPainted(false); //to make the borders transparent
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at [setOpaque(true/false); Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451990/setopaquetrue-false-java) it has information about setOpaque method of Component class.

Answer (score 3):

```
I want to give the buttons a transparent (glossy) look.
```

- [Translucent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) and [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)
- [Transparent with AlphaComposite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720207/714968)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.btnOptions.setFont(new Font("Forte", Font.PLAIN, 33)); 
this.btnOptions.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
this.btnOptions.setOpaque(false);
this.btnOptions.setContentAreaFilled(false);
this.btnOptions.setBorderPainted(false);
this.btnOptions.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```