# How can i make a JPopupMenu transparent?

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jpopupmenu, jpopup

I'd like to customize the look of `JPopupMenu` so i made a custom class extending the JPopupMenu class on i overrode the `paintComponent` method as i would do for any component i need to customize.

```
public class CustomPopupMenu extends JPopupMenu {

    @Override
    public paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //custom draw
    }
}
```

The only problem i have right know is that i'm not able to make the `JPopupMenu` transparent. I though `setOpaque(false)` would be enough, i was wrong.

How can i make a `JPopupMenu` transparent?

Comment: never tried, but I never heard about any issue with [Translucent Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: @mKorbel a jpopupmenu is a window?

Comment: sorry my endless lazyness, please see ma answer here :-)

Comment: !) What is the ***point*** of making a `JPopupMenu` transparent?  If your answer is 'to make my app. a "Killer App."' then my advice is to apply your expertise to things other than futzing with the look and feel.  Because that does not make a 'killer app.'.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And i don't get the point of your comment. I need to make a jpopupmenu transparent to draw rounded borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a popup menu is that it may be realized as a top-level container (Window), and a window is opaque, no matter what value you set with setOpaque(), its opaque. But windows can be made translucent, too.

You can *hack* it by forcing the use of a heavyweight popup and brutally altering its opacity. Try this as a starting base for experiments (Java7):

```
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TranslucentPopup extends JPopupMenu {

    {
        // need to disable that to work
        setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        if (visible == isVisible())
            return;
        super.setVisible(visible);
        if (visible) {
            // attempt to set tranparency
            try {
                Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
                w.setOpacity(0.667F);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Note that it will *not* make submenus translucent!

Comment: hmm .. why reflection? SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this) should be good enough to get hold of the containing window

Comment: Good point. I hacked the reflection part while I was experimenting when I still hadn't put in setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false), at that point I got the effect that the *parent* window became translucent. Will update the code. Thanks.

Comment: for subMenus, do the same for a custom JMenu: override setPopupMenuVisible and force the popup's windowAncestor to be translucent

Answer (score 4):

> jpopupmenu is a window?

yes [JPopup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) is container, for example

[image]

code for Java6 (have to change imports for Java7)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TranslucentWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JMenuItem m_mniInsertRow;
    private JMenuItem m_mniInsertScrip;
    private JMenuItem m_mniDeleterRow;
    private JMenuItem m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip;
    private JMenuItem m_mniSetAlert;

    public TranslucentWindow() {
        super("Test translucent window");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JButton("test"));
        add(new JCheckBox("test"));
        add(new JRadioButton("test"));
        add(new JProgressBar(0, 100));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };
        panel.add(new JLabel("Very long textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "));
        add(panel);
        final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        m_mniInsertRow = new JMenuItem("Insert a Row");
        m_mniInsertRow.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniInsertScrip = new JMenuItem("Insert a Scrip");
        m_mniInsertScrip.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniDeleterRow = new JMenuItem("Delete a Row");
        m_mniDeleterRow.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip = new JMenuItem("Delete a Expired Scrip");
        m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniSetAlert = new JMenuItem("Set Alert");
        m_mniSetAlert.setOpaque(false);
        popupMenu.add(m_mniInsertRow);
        popupMenu.add(m_mniInsertScrip);
        popupMenu.addSeparator();
        popupMenu.add(m_mniDeleterRow);
        popupMenu.add(m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip);
        popupMenu.add(new JSeparator());
        popupMenu.add(m_mniSetAlert);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    int x = e.getX();
                    int y = e.getY();
                    popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), x, y);
                }
            }
        });
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Window w = new TranslucentWindow();
                w.setVisible(true);
                com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(w, 0.7f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

interesting support for `Translucency` and `Nimbus L&F`, especially `Painter` reproducing quite correct `Color` (Gradiend too on movement over the screen), ligth version with important changes for JPopupMenu, still from Java6

image

[image]

from code

```
import com.sun.java.swing.Painter;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TranslucentWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    private JMenuItem m_mniInsertRow = new JMenuItem("Insert a Row");
    private JMenuItem m_mniInsertScrip = new JMenuItem("Delete a Row");
    private JMenuItem m_mniDeleterRow = new JMenuItem("Insert a Scrip");
    private JMenuItem m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip = new JMenuItem("Delete a Expired Scrip");
    private JMenuItem m_mniSetAlert = new JMenuItem("Set Alert");

    public TranslucentWindow() {
        super("Test translucent window");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JButton("test"));
        add(new JCheckBox("test"));
        add(new JRadioButton("test"));
        add(new JProgressBar(0, 100));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };
        panel.add(new JLabel("Very long textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "));
        panel.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
        add(panel);
        m_mniInsertRow.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniInsertScrip.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniDeleterRow.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip.setOpaque(false);
        m_mniSetAlert.setOpaque(false);
        popupMenu.add(m_mniInsertRow);
        popupMenu.add(m_mniInsertScrip);
        popupMenu.addSeparator();
        popupMenu.add(m_mniDeleterRow);
        popupMenu.add(m_mniDeleteExpiredScrip);
        popupMenu.add(new JSeparator());
        popupMenu.add(m_mniSetAlert);
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("nimbusOrange", (new Color(127, 255, 191)));
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("PopupMenu[Enabled].backgroundPainter",
                            new FillPainter(new Color(127, 255, 191)));

                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Window w = new TranslucentWindow();
                w.setVisible(true);
                com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(w, 0.7f);
            }
        });
    }

    static class FillPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {

        private final Color color;

        FillPainter(Color c) {
            color = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting that the popup kind-of inherits the window's transparency (as long as no part of it is outside the main window)

Comment: btw: please do me a favour and edit the code to use setComponentPopupMenu (instead of opening on mouseReleased, doing so should be banned from all code!)

Comment: @kleopatra When the popup is entirely within the window, its realized as a simple JPanel inside the windows component hierarchy. Stumbled over it when trying to hack my solution. If setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) is used, the popup will be consistently realized in a window. Probably this is an optimization left over from early Swing days when it was famous for being slow...

Comment: @kleopatra for your endless pleasure to read the """correct""" answers on this forum, I'll do that

Comment: @Durandal thanks for your question, learning item of day, Nimbus with Painter and Translucency support on WinXP / Java6, heloooo JavaFX can you heard me, one more year without you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to extend `JPopupMenu` class, just make your menu non-opaque and then make the `JMenuItems` transparent instead (and non-opaque).

```
public class CustomMenuItem extends JMenuItem {
        public void paint(Graphics g) { 
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create(); 
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.2f)); 
                super.paint(g2d); 
                g2d.dispose(); 
        } 
}
```

[image]

OR, do the opposite, extend `JPopupMenu` to make it transparent and keep both the menu and items non-opaque (this way there will be no opaque border of the menu like above).

EDIT:

Note that (unfortunately) it does not work when the popup menu exceeds the frame bounds, as @Durandal remarked.

Though you could try to make some calculations and change location of popup (when needed) to keep it always inside the frame.

Comment: @Durandal [no issue AlphaComposite is proper of ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6720207/714968) (@Rempelos +1)

Comment: Nope, try opening the popup so its *partially* outside the frame bounds. Epic. Or alternately setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) on the popup.

Comment: @mKorbel It applies to *both* you and Rempelos. When the popup is realized in a heavyweight container (as it must when its not located within window bounds) the popup window will not be translucent.

Comment: @Durandal: true, when partially outside the frame it's not transparent (noticed that after your comment actually). But still down vote was not necessary ;)

Comment: @Rempelos Don't take it personally. I downvoted simply because it didn't work for me. Under Win Classic, it simply messed up the rendering for me when I tested it (item was transparent, parent panel was not, so it just became fainter).

Comment: @Durandal, fair enough, no problem ;)

Comment: apart from not really working, I don't like it because it's tweaking the items - that's not really an option because it would require to manually create all items vs letting the menu/popup handle the creation given an Action.

Comment: @kleopatra you can also do the opposite, extend JPopupMenu and make it non-opaque & transparent instead of the menu items which will be just non-opaque. It may be better that way (no opaque border of the menu like the image above)

Answer (score 1):

See this excellent 2008 article [Translucent and Shaped Swing Windows](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html) by Kirill Grouchnikov.

Based on examples given in the above article and code borrowed from the JGoodies project, you can install a custom popup Look & Feel using the following 2 classes:

1. TranslucentPopup is the customized Popup, used by JPopupMenu:

   ```
   /**
    * Translucent Popup
    *
    * @author Kirill Grouchnikov [https://www.java.net/pub/au/275]
    */
   public class TranslucentPopup extends Popup {
       final JWindow popupWindow;

       TranslucentPopup(Component contents, int ownerX, int ownerY) {
           // create a new heavyweight window
           popupWindow = new JWindow();
           // mark the popup with partial opacity
           com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(popupWindow, 0.7f);
           // determine the popup location
           popupWindow.setLocation(ownerX, ownerY);
           // add the contents to the popup
           popupWindow.getContentPane().add(contents, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           contents.invalidate();
           JComponent parent = (JComponent) contents.getParent();
           // set a custom border
           parent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder());
       }

       public void show() {
           popupWindow.setVisible(true);
           popupWindow.pack();
           // mark the window as non-opaque, so that the
           // border pixels take on the per-pixel opacity
           com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(popupWindow, false);
       }

       public void hide() {
           popupWindow.setVisible(false);
       }
   }
   ```
2. TranslucentPopupFactory is requried to install the custom Look and Feel:

   ```
   /**
    * Translucent Popup Factory
    *
    * @author Kirill Grouchnikov [https://www.java.net/pub/au/275]
    * @author Karsten Lentzsch (JGoodies project)
    */
   public class TranslucentPopupFactory extends PopupFactory {
       /**
        * The PopupFactory used before this PopupFactory has been installed in
        * {@code #install}. Used to restored the original state in
        * {@code #uninstall}.
        */
       protected final PopupFactory storedFactory;

       protected TranslucentPopupFactory(PopupFactory originalFactory) {
           storedFactory = originalFactory;
       }

       public Popup getPopup(Component owner, Component contents, int x, int y) throws IllegalArgumentException {
           // A more complete implementation would cache and reuse popups
           return new TranslucentPopup(contents, x, y);
       }

       /**
         * Utility method to install the custom Popup Look and feel.
         * Call this method once during your application start-up.
         *
         * @author Karsten Lentzsch (JGoodies project)
         */
       public static void install() {
           PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
           if (factory instanceof TranslucentPopupFactory) {
               return;
           }

           PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(new TranslucentPopupFactory(factory));
       }

       /**
         * Utility method to uninstall the custom Popup Look and feel
         * @author Karsten Lentzsch (JGoodies project)
         */
       public static void uninstall() {
           PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
           if (!(factory instanceof TranslucentPopupFactory)) {
               return;
           }

           PopupFactory stored = ((TranslucentPopupFactory) factory).storedFactory;
           PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(stored);
       }
   }
   ```

The result is that all Popups (including JPopupMenu and perhaps also ToolTips) will now be Translucent, and optionally have a custom border:
[image: Translucent Context Menu shown on World Wind Context Menu example app]